# How to XmlSerialize System.Drawing.Font class

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

The class`System.Drawing.Font` is not XML Serializable since it doesn't have a default (empty) constructor.
Is there some work around or alternative way to serialize `Font` nevertheless?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Edit:** I updated the code according to [Regent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940127/how-to-xmlserialize-system-drawing-font-class/1940307#1940307) suggestion to use `FontConverter`, while preserving the ability to use the `SerializableFont` as regular `Font`.

```
public class SerializableFont
{
    public SerializableFont()
    {
        FontValue = null;
    }

    public SerializableFont(Font font)
    {
        FontValue = font;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Font FontValue { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FontValue")]
    public string SerializeFontAttribute
    {
        get
        {
            return FontXmlConverter.ConvertToString(FontValue);
        }
        set
        {
            FontValue = FontXmlConverter.ConvertToFont(value);
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator Font(SerializableFont serializeableFont)
    {
        if (serializeableFont == null )
            return null;
        return serializeableFont.FontValue;
    }

    public static implicit operator SerializableFont(Font font)
    {
        return new SerializableFont(font);
    }
}

public static class FontXmlConverter
{
    public static string ConvertToString(Font font)
    {
        try
        {
            if (font != null)
            {
                TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));
                return converter.ConvertToString(font);
            }
            else 
                return null;
        }
        catch { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to convert"); }
        return null;
    }
    public static Font ConvertToFont(string fontString)
    {
        try
        {
            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));
            return (Font)converter.ConvertFromString(fontString);
        }
        catch { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to convert"); }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage: When you have a `Font` property, declare it as `SerializableFont`. This will allow it to be serialized, while the implicit cast will handle the conversion for you.

Instead of writing:

```
Font MyFont {get;set;}
```

Write:

```
SerializableFont MyFont {get;set;}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking you have ended up with some xml, but in reality you've eliminated all the semantic richness of xml by just dumping its binary contents in a base64 encoded text element. IMHO It's really not "xml serialized" in the useful sense of the word.
It's not like you can "see" any of the Font properties in the xml, without deserializing first, nor can you XPath it, transform it, iterate over it, etc

Answer (score 5):

I use a serializable font, somewhat different from [Elad's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940127/how-to-xmlserialize-system-drawing-font-class/1940146#1940146).

In my serializable data-entities I hide (`[XmlIgnore]`) the property with the `Font` type and expose the property with the `SerializableFont` type, which is "eaten" by the serializer.

Note that this is applicable to the `XmlSerializer` only.

```
/// <summary>
/// Font descriptor, that can be xml-serialized
/// </summary>
public class SerializableFont
{
    public string FontFamily { get; set; }
    public GraphicsUnit GraphicsUnit { get; set; }
    public float Size { get; set; }
    public FontStyle Style { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Intended for xml serialization purposes only
    /// </summary>
    private SerializableFont() { }

    public SerializableFont(Font f)
    {
        FontFamily = f.FontFamily.Name;
        GraphicsUnit = f.Unit;
        Size = f.Size;
        Style = f.Style;
    }

    public static SerializableFont FromFont(Font f)
    {
        return new SerializableFont(f);
    }

    public Font ToFont()
    {
        return new Font(FontFamily, Size, Style,
            GraphicsUnit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A suggestion on how to do this by implementing a wrapper class that is serializable is given on the [MSDN page for the Font class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes - a wrapper around the class that is genuinely xml serializable is the way to go IMHO

Answer (score 2):

`System.Drawing.Font` have an associated [`FontConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontconverter.aspx) class and I would manually converting it:

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableFont
{
    public SerializableFont()
    {
        this.Font = null;
    }

    public SerializableFont(Font font)
    {
        this.Font = font;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Font Font { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Font")]
    public string FontString
    {
        get
        {
            if (font != null)
            {
                TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));

                return converter.ConvertToString(this.Font);
            }
            else return null;
        }
        set
        {
            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));

            this.Font = converter.ConvertFromString(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks! Although interested to know why not just use `FontConverter converter = new FontConverter();` or is this ok?

Comment: Just found this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontconverter.aspx): It says _Access the FontConverter class through the TypeDescriptor class by calling the GetConverter method_.  But still not sure why.

Comment: @Ben, I reckon there might be several reasons for this, firstly `TypeDescriptor` might have already created instance of `FontConverter ` so you don't need to waste memory creating one every single time; secondly they might want to replace `FontConverter` with something else in future versions of the Framework and using `TypeDescriptor` gives more flexibility on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the DataContractSerializer.

```
        Font fnt = new Font("Arial", 1);
        MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Font), new[] { typeof(FontStyle), typeof(GraphicsUnit) });
        dcs.WriteObject(data, fnt);
        string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is overly complicated and still doesn't work with PropertyGrid.  Here is the simple and easy solution.

First put following 2 methods in the class.

```
protected static string FontToString(Font font)
{
    try
    {
        if (font == null)
            return null;

        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));
        return converter.ConvertToString(font);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}

protected static Font StringToFont(string text)
{
    try
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));
        return (Font)converter.ConvertFromString(text);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then add properties.

```
[Category("General")]
[XmlIgnore]
public Font LogFont
{
    get
    {
        return StringToFont(LogFontValue);
    }
    set
    {
        LogFontValue = FontToString(value);
    }
}

[Browsable(false)]
public string LogFontValue { get; set; } = "Lucida Console, 12pt";
```