# Serializing Font Object from C# and Deserializing on Java

Tags: c#, java, serialization, fonts

Using @Elad solution at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940127/how-to-xmlserialize-system-drawing-font-class) I could serialize and de-serialize a Font using C# but I need to de-serialize it in Java.  Is there a way to achieve it?

If someone has any good article on doing this for any other object it could be helpful.

Comment: By "serialize a font", do you mean just the key properties *of* the font (size, style, family, etc) - or do you expect to serialize the *actual font*?

Comment: Are you sure that font object  will be of any use in java environment?

Comment: @MarcGravell yes i mean Serializing Font properties ,Size ,Style ect.

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda if there isn't a Font which is Specified into an XML than i would use any of the Font ,which is Valid only for FontFamily because Size Style ect could be loaded from Deserialized Object .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Elad's answer, the System.Drawing.Font is converted to XML, and then to a pure binary form.  On the Java, side, it's pretty trivial to deserialize from binary to XML, but from there, you will have to know what you plan on doing with the XML.  Do you have a java class you are wanting/needing to use?

Comment: Yes java.awt.Font @claymore1977

Comment: According to the java.awt.Font API doc (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) there is a constructor that takes a Map.  I imagine that you can leverage that for what you need.

Comment: well i thought about another Solution ,but that's beyond my experience with Java ,if i could use something similar to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx which accept's a Font File ,transfering the Font Files wont be hard.

Comment: What's wrong with using a Map ?  On the other hand, throwing around Font Files might work....

Answer (score 0):

You can try Protocol Buffers.

Its serialized form is language neutral and you can use it on serialize on C# and deserialize on java side.