# how to serialize font

Tags: c#, xml, fonts, binary-serialization

I have one class and I set `[Serializable]` attribute to that class.

in this class I define one font class member.but when I am trying to serialize it gives me an error like "system.drawing.font cannot be serialized"

Comment: Are you XMLSerialising the class ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940127/how-to-xmlserialize-system-drawing-font-class

Comment: Instead of serializing the entire Font class, you might just serialize it's font-family name + key properties like size and bold/italic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did this in a recent project:

```
[XmlIgnore()]
public Font Font {
  get { return mFont; }
  set { mFont = value; }
}

[Browsable(false)]
public string FontHidden {
  get { return FontSerializationHelper.Serialize(mFont); }
  set { mFont = FontSerializationHelper.Deserialize(value); }
}
```

The FontSerializationHelper class is as follows:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[TypeConverter(typeof(FontConverter))]
internal class FontSerializationHelper
{
    public static Font Deserialize(string value)
    {
        object m = Regex.Match(value, "^(?<Font>[\\w ]+),(?<Size>(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?))(,(?<Style>(R|[BIU]{1,3})))?$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (m.Success) 
        {
            if (m.Groups.Count < 4 || m.Groups(3).Value == "R") 
            {
                return new Font(m.Groups("Font").Value, Single.Parse(m.Groups("Size").Value));
            } 
            else 
            {
                object fs = m.Groups(3).Value.IndexOf("B") >= 0 ? FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular | m.Groups(3).Value.IndexOf("I") >= 0 ? FontStyle.Italic : FontStyle.Regular | m.Groups(3).Value.IndexOf("U") >= 0 ? FontStyle.Underline : FontStyle.Regular;
                return new Font(m.Groups("Font").Value, Single.Parse(m.Groups("Size").Value), fs);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            throw new FormatException("Value is not properly formatted.");
        }
    }

    public static string Serialize(Font value)
    {
        string str;

        str = value.Name + "," + value.Size.ToString() + ",";
        if (value.Style == FontStyle.Regular) 
        {
            str += "R";
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (value.Bold) str += "B";
            if (value.Italic) str += "I";
            if (value.Underline) str += "U";
        }

        return str;
    }
}
```

Note that I'm just saving Font Family, Size and Style information. You may want to add more to it.

Answer (score 5):

Even if this question is old, here are my solutions:

**Solution #1** (this one lose `GdiCharSet` and `GdiVerticalFont` parameter):

```
private Font font = new Font("Arial", 13f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, 0, false);

[XmlIgnore()]
public Font Font {
    get { return font; }
    set { font = value; }
}

[Browsable(false)]
public string FontSerialize {
    get { return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font)).ConvertToInvariantString(font); }
    set { font = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font)).ConvertFromInvariantString(value) as Font; }
}
```

**Solution #2** (utilizing *all* `Font` constructor parameter):

Properties:

```
[XmlIgnore()]
public Font Font {
    get { return font; }
    set { font = value; }
}

[Browsable(false)]
public string FontSerialize {
    get { return FontSerializationHelper.ToString(font); }
    set { font = FontSerializationHelper.FromString(value); }
}
```

FontSerializationHelper class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(FontConverter))]
static public class FontSerializationHelper {

    static public Font FromString(string value) {
        var parts = value.Split(':');
        return new Font(
            parts[0],                                                   // FontFamily.Name
            float.Parse(parts[1]),                                      // Size
            EnumSerializationHelper.FromString<FontStyle>(parts[2]),    // Style
            EnumSerializationHelper.FromString<GraphicsUnit>(parts[3]), // Unit
            byte.Parse(parts[4]),                                       // GdiCharSet
            bool.Parse(parts[5])                                        // GdiVerticalFont
        );
    }

    static public string ToString(Font font) {
        return font.FontFamily.Name
                + ":" + font.Size
                + ":" + font.Style
                + ":" + font.Unit
                + ":" + font.GdiCharSet
                + ":" + font.GdiVerticalFont
                ;
    }
}
```

EnumSerializationHelper class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumConverter))]
static public class EnumSerializationHelper {

    static public T FromString<T>(string value) {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't serialize a Font.  You can't serialize most GDI resources.

You can try to use the FontConverter class to serialize it to a string for you.